# Hibernate IndexColumn with Map

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to map a collection (of type map).

```
Below are the tables
Product:
  PID -  primary key
  NAME

ProductProperties:
   ID - primary key auto_increment
   PID - FK references Product(ID)(INDEXED)
   KEY - (INDEXED)
   VALUE
```

And below is the hbm file used for mapping

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.test.Product" table="product" catalog="cart">
        <id name="pid" type="long">
            <column name="pid" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name" length="100" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <map name="properties" table="properties"  cascade="all">
            <key column="pid" not-null="true"/>
            <map-key column="key" type="string"/>
            <element column="value" type="string"/>
        </map>
    </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

In many examples, I see  instead of  .

I have few questions regarding this.

1. Why IndexColumn used instead of map-key?
2. Which is better? IndexColumn OR map-key
3. Where can I find a detailed documentation to learn about IndexColumn and map-key?

Kindly help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You mean to ask the difference between

```
<map ...>
    <map-key .../>
</map>
```

and

```
<map ...>
    <index .../>
</map>
```

At runtime, they are interpreted exactly the same. I guess <index> was kept for backwards compatibility with hibernate 2.0, where they used the same element for <map> and <list>. In hibernate 3.0, <map-key> is preferred.

For documentation, I only use the reference, but it doesn't give you much detail. Unless you would read the DTD: http://www.jboss.org/dtd/hibernate/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd.